# R transpose and group by

Tags: r, aggregate, transpose

I have a data set that looks like:

```
Client   Smoke

0021     Y
0021     Y
0021     Y
```

and I want the data to look like:

```
ClientNo   Smoke 1 Smoke 2 Smoke 3  
0021         Y      Y     Y
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `dcast()` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(DT, Client ~ rowid(Client, prefix = "Smoke "), value.var = "Smoke")
#   Client Smoke 1 Smoke 2 Smoke 3
#1:     21       Y       Y       Y
```

**Data**

```
DT <- fread("Client   Smoke
            0021     Y
            0021     Y
            0021     Y")
```